# Google Analytics: How to combine page metrics after modifying the structure of a URL

Tags: google-analytics

So I changed my website's URL structure for product pages from /products-services/xyz to /solutions/xyz and redirected the old URLs to the new ones. Note: The domain has not changed.

However, I did not realize in Google Analytics that historical metrics from /products-services pages would not be compared to the new URL. This makes it impossible to compare month to month or year to year performance for specific product pages.

How can I tell Google to combine the metrics for these product pages? The only thing changed was the URL structure to "solutions".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is, you can't. GA doesn't process the data you send except in specific, predefined ways. However, you may be able to get at the data you are hoping for with a custom report.

There is a set of 4 dimensions in GA related to URL path directory by directory: Page path level 1-4. You changed level 1 but not level 2, and we can use the dimensions in the custom report to combine level 2 across these two level 1 values.

In your custom report, set whatever metrics you are interested in under the Metric Group. Not every metric and dimension are compatible, but anything that appears in the Behavior > Site Content > All Pages report should likely work.

Set the dimension to Page path level 2.

Then, in the Filter, you'll include Page path level 1 matching the regex `/(products-services|solutions)/`. This will then show only the two versions of your product pages.

[image: screenshot of custom report set up as described previously in answer]

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you so much!!